# Three.js: Takes too much time to render first frame

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js

I use Three.js (with WegGL) to render alternating scenes of many image tiles (a few thousands) animating at space. Animations are handled by Tween.js. I use Chrome for testing.

To optimize the image loading, I preload all the texture images before the first scene is displayed. All textures are then saved in memory as `THREE.Texture`. Now when I prepare a scene for display, I do something like this:

```
let tile = null, tweens = [], cameraZ = 1000;
for (let y =  0; y < rows; y++){
    for (let x =  0; x < columns; x++){
        tile = await this.createTile(x, y, [textureSize]);
        tile.position.x = x * this.tileWidth - this.picWidth / 2;
        tile.position.y = -y * this.tileHeight + this.picHeight / 2;
        tile.position.z = cameraZ * 1.1;

        tweens.push(new TWEEN.Tween(tile.position)
            .to({z: 0}, 4000)
            .delay(200 + x * 120 + Math.random() * 1000)
            .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Cubic.InOut));
        this.scene.add(tile);
    }
}
tweens.map(t => t.start());
```

The scene preparation also include camera and a point light, and takes about 400 ms to complete.

I then render the scene like this:

```
function render(){
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    TWEEN.update();
    renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
}
render();
```

Everything is displayed properly by when measuring some processing durations, I see that the **first** rendering call takes about 1400 ms! Other calls take between 70 to 100 ms.

My final goal is to have multiple scenes like this, play one after another without any freezes. Given that all the required assets are already loaded, what might be the problem and how can I optimize that?

Thanks

Comment: you're not using requestAnimationFrame correctly https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: I don't believe this is the problem. I follow the code from Three.js example. for instance look at the code here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_animation_cloth.html

Answer (score 0):

During the first frame of rendering, all of your assets and shaders are being compiled and uploaded to the GPU. If you want to avoid that, you'll have to do some tricks behind the scenes.. like forcibly rendering each object once after you load it, perhaps by adding it to a single scene, and calling renderer.render on it. Depending on what the bottleneck is (shader compilation vs asset uploading) this may or may not help.. but the workaround is doing some kind of pre-rendering to force the uploads to the card one at a time, rather than all at once.

Also, as a previous commenter noted, your render loop above has a typo in it.

it should be requestAnimationFrame(render);

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that. Just noticed the typo here. It doesn't exist on the original code :-)